# JavaScriptのスコープについて教えてください。

Tags: javascript

下のようにJavaScriptでファンクションの外の引数にアクセスしたいのですが、
ローカルスコープと名前が同じだと出来ませんでしょうか？
thisやglobalでアクセスできるとうれしいのですが検索しても見つからなかったので
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。
よろしくおねがいします。

```
var param;
FunctionA = function(param) {
    this.param = param;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ある例外を除いて、できません。

その例外とは、関数の外側の `param` がグローバルスコープで定義されている場合です。この時には、Webブラウザならば `window.param` で、NodeJSならば `global.param` でと言った具合にアクセスが可能です。

質問のコードがグローバルスコープにあたるかどうかは断定できませんが、文字通りに **このコードだけをWebブラウザで実行する** ならばグローバルスコープであるといえますので、 `window.param` でアクセスできます。